# Can we have a sql express-like database using MySql

Tags: mysql

Can we create a sql express-like database using MySql.

meaning: the database files can reside in the project's directory and can work on any machine having sql express installed.

Does MySql provide such a facility? and if so, how can this be done

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nope**. This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Firebird SQL for that kind databases, especially coupled with the embedded engine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [libmysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/libmysqld.html).  Basically, it lets you embed a MySQL server in a C/C++ program.  Not sure how it works, as i've never used it.  But it's supposedly a standard part of MySQL now, so it could be available to anyone that has MySQL installed.

I imagine you could have your own folder of tables and such, point the embedded server at it, and go.